# rule has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations

Tags: antlr, grammar, xtext

I have an error (like said in the title) with one rule that i dont know how resolve.

i have written the following rule :

```
FunctionArguments returns FunctionArgs::IFunctionArguments :
    FunctionArgumentsNormal
    | FunctionArgumentsForIter
    ;

FunctionArgumentsNormal returns FunctionArgs::IFunctionArguments :
    {FunctionArgs::FunctionArguments} args+=Expression (',' args+=Expression)* 
    | {FunctionArgs::FunctionArguments} argNames+=NamedArguments (',' argNames+=NamedArguments)*
    ;

FunctionArgumentsForIter returns FunctionArgs::IFunctionArguments :
    {FunctionArgs::FunctionArgumentsIterator} exp=Expression 'for' iterators=ForIterator
    ;
```

Could you help me to resolve it by left-factoring this expression or give any others solutions please ?

Comment: Please state, whether you want to use the Xtext grammar or the ANTLR grammar. They are quite different and this affects how left recursion can be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a LL grammar you can have no left-recursion. The problem is that a LL parser can choose to make a derivation like this:
FunctionArguments -> FunctionArgumentsNormal -> FunctionArguments -> FunctionArgumentsNormal ...
Your grammar contains what is called indirect left recursion. You can find an example in this wikipedia-article which also contains a solution as to how you can fix it: [Left-Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion).
A good place to start is by (I suppose you already have done this) writing your grammar in a very simple way without all the annotations and things included in your example. If you have the grammar on the simple form:

```
S -> A | B
B -> "terminal1" B
  |  b
A -> a "terminal2"
```

it is much easier to do the necessary rewriting.

Comment: i think that it's going to help me. i will try later.. meanwhile, thx

Comment: I know, it's been some time. Still I am not sure, I understand how the grammar given by the OP can generate the above mentioned cycle.
At least not from the given grammar snippet. Where does a derivation from `FunctionalArgumentsNormal -> FunctionArguments` happen?

Comment: The derivation `FunctionalArgumentsNormal -> FunctionArguments` happens when applying the 2nd rule (either side of the or sign `|`):
`{FunctionArgs::FunctionArguments} args+=Expression (',' args+=Expression)*`